# How to insert new <div> on a button click at the cursor position of existing <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

`this.$el.find('#divname').append(newDivHtml)` will append to the `newDivHTML` to existing `div`. However, I was looking at this scenario:

1. On the existing `div1` user edits some free text and clicks a button
2. on click of the button, a popupview shows up a list of options.
3. selecting one option inserts the `newDivHtml` into the cursor position of underlaying `div1`.

**I tried**: http://jsfiddle.net/jwvha/1/

```
 function pasteHtmlAtCaret(html) {
        var sel, range;
        if (window.getSelection) {
        // IE9 and non-IE
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();

            // Range.createContextualFragment() would be useful here but is
            // non-standard and not supported in all browsers (IE9, for one)
            var el = document.createElement("div");
            el.innerHTML = html;
            var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), node, lastNode;
            while ( (node = el.firstChild) ) {
                lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
            }
            range.insertNode(frag);

            // Preserve the selection
            if (lastNode) {
                range = range.cloneRange();
                range.setStartAfter(lastNode);
                range.collapse(true);
                sel.removeAllRanges();
                sel.addRange(range);
            }
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        // IE < 9
        document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(html);
    }
}

2. doesn't seems to work for that.$e1.find('#sectionContentSimple').insertAdjacentHTML(100, newhtml);
```

Comment: So, you are missing the options dialog, is this right?

Comment: the options are all working fine, the challenge is to insert the option text which is a newDivHtml in the underlaying DIV at the cursor position. the jQuery Api's like Append,AppendTo,Before,InsertAfter all doesn't seems to work.

Comment: What's the expected result of your fiddle and what is working wrong?

Comment: its works in jsfiddle, however, doesn't seems to work when I integrate in my application. I guess, the focus is getting lost. Is there a better way to find the cursor position of the existing div before a new div gets inserted into it and how to insert the new div into the existing div?

Comment: It is impossible to help here if it can not be reproduced with some example code.

Comment: I used your jsFiddle code and tested it with all browser and it seems, it is working fine. You should try that way. Are you getting any error in console?

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought without delving into the code too deeply, have you tried saving the clicked element to a variable so that you can access it later, rather than relying on it retaining focus?